# How to remove the header and entire column from CSV file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, .net-core

I am converting a JSON file to CSV. Once after the conversion is done, I need to check for columns that doesn't have values for any of its rows. If that is the case, then the entire column should be removed with the header.

[image: Actual CSV File]

In the above example, the column 'Retiring Period' doesnt have any value in any of its rows. So, the updated CSV should look like below.

[image: Output CSV File]

This is what is expected and needs to done using C#. Any help on this would be much appreciable.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution might be something like

```
class Program {
    static void Main (string[] args) {
        GenerateNonEmptyCSV ("data.json", "data", "output.csv");
    }

    public static void GenerateNonEmptyCSV (string inputJsonFilePath_, string arrayName_, string outputFilePath_) {
        //Read data from json file
        DataSet dataSet;
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader (inputJsonFilePath_)) {
            dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet> (tr.ReadToEnd ());
        }
        DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[arrayName_];

        //Get Valid column index into a hashset
        var validColumns = new HashSet<int> ();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
            if (validColumns.Count == dataTable.Columns.Count) { break; } //All columns are valid, no need to loop through rows anymore
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dataTable.Columns.Count; columnIndex++) {
                if (validColumns.Contains (columnIndex)) { continue; }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (row?.ItemArray[columnIndex]?.ToString ())) { validColumns.Add (columnIndex); }
            }
        }

        //output valid columns into csv file
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter (outputFilePath_)) {
            string[] columnData = new string[validColumns.Count];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (int columnIndex in validColumns) {
                columnData[index++] = dataTable.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName;
            }
            tw.WriteLine (string.Join (",", columnData)); //Write column header

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
                string[] rowData = new string[validColumns.Count];
                index = 0;
                foreach (int columnIndex in validColumns) {
                    rowData[index++] = row?.ItemArray[columnIndex]?.ToString ();
                }
                tw.WriteLine (string.Join (",", rowData));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample data used

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "EmployeeId": "1",
        "EmployeeName": "Name1",
        "RetiringPeriod": "",
        "Salary":"80k"
    },
    {
        "EmployeeId": "2",
        "EmployeeName": "Name2",
        "RetiringPeriod": "",
        "Salary":"60k"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks much @Vishwa This really helped me to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to move from collections to .CSV files and back and you have an Employees collection that contains your data (including the empty Retirement) you could generate a collection of EmployeesWithoutRetirements and save that as a .CSV.

```
void Main()
{
    var employeeWithoutRetirements = (List<EmployeeWithoutRetirement>) Employees
        .Select(x => new EmployeeWithoutRetirement {
            EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID,
            EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName, 
            Salary = x.Salary });
    }
class EmployeeWithoutRetirement
{
    public int EmployeeID  {get;set;}
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```